# In these sentences, did I use the correct conjugation for, "Moved"? I used "nos mudabamos"

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, sintaxis, conjugación

Esta es la oración:

> Mi habitacíon es rosa. Cuando nos la primera nos mudabamos, mi hermano no quiere la habitacion rosa, asi que *tomado/(tomaba)* eso habitacion.
>
> ---
>
> My room is pink. When we first moved, my brother did not want the pink room, so I took that room.

I am a beginner, so please forgive the sentences that are most likely riddled with mistakes. I find conjugation difficult since there are many more tenses than in english. If there is a better way to say the sentences above, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! In this kind of questions it usually is a good idea to mention the Spanish variant you want to use, as there may be regional differences. For instace, in Spain you don't usually use the verb "tomar" in this context, but "quedar": _Me quedé con la habitación_. If you want to use that sentence in a given Spanish-speaking country, please add it to the question and you will get better answers.

Comment: By the way, does [the answer to this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/417/12637) answer yours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving all other mistakes aside, let's concentrate on the verb tense.

Generally speaking, **the perfective aspect indicates completed actions and the imperfective indicates ongoing actions (incomplete or recurring)**. In this case, you are talking about a completed action: you moved and, as a result of that, you were in a new house, where the rest of the action happened (your brother did not like one of the rooms and so on). So you have to use the perfective aspect: *mudamos* rather than *mudábamos*.

As for the other verbs, you have to use the perfective too for the third verb (*took*), which is an instantaneous action and, therefore, completed as soon as it is started. But the second verb (*want*) is tricky; you can consider that it is also an instantaneous action (there were two rooms, your brother said no to one of them, and then you took it), or an ongoing action (your brother had been complaining about that room for some time and at some point you decided to take it). So you can actually use the perfective or the imperfective.

Putting all together, and fixing the translation a bit, you have these two choices:

> 1. Mi habitación es rosa. Cuando nos mudamos, mi hermano no **quiso** la habitación rosa, así que la tomé yo.
> 2. Mi habitación es rosa. Cuando nos mudamos, mi hermano no **quería** la habitación rosa, así que la tomé yo.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

1) *ENGLISH*:

> "My *room* is pink. When we first moved my brother didn't want the pink room. So, I *took* that room."

2) SPANISH (TRANSLITERATION FROM ENGLISH POINT 1):

> "Mi cuarto/*alcoba* es rosada. Cuando nosotros primero nos mudamos mi hermano no quería el cuarto/*la alcoba* rosada. Entonces, yo *tomé* ese cuarto/*esa alcoba*.

3) SPANISH (TRANSLATION FROM POINT 1):

> "Como cuando nos mudamos mi hermano vió que las paredes de uno de los cuartos/ *las alcobas* eran rosadas, a él no le gusto. Y ahora... ese *es* mi cuarto"

4) ENGLISH (TRANSLITERATED FROM SPANISH POINT 3):

> "Because when we moved my brother saw that one of *the rooms* had pink walls, he didn't *like* it. Now... that *is* my room."

NOTE:

The reason that I did not translate the verbal conjugation of *take*: *took* in POINT 1) which means *coger/tomar/agarrar* and I used the verbal conjugation of *be* (*ser/estar*): *es* [see POINT 3)] which in Spanish means *is* [see POINT 4)].  It is because, in some countries, those verbs mean having sex. So...

P.S.*

— *Quiso* is the past tense verbal conjugation to the verb *want* and is used in sentences In Spanish.

— *Quería* is the past tense verbal conjugation to the verb *want* and is used in clauses.

—The verb *gustar* which means *like* in English. It is more common as opposed to *want*.

*[*Post Script* thats in English equivalent to P.D which is Post Data in Spanish. It is another way of saying *btw* in English phone texting which means *by the way* or *a propós* in Spanish]

Comment: Dario, puedes echarle un vistazo a [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). El markdown es muy útil en estas lindes, pero necesita cierto (pequeño) aprendizaje.

Comment: Darío, veo que eres nuevo y estás haciendo un montón de contribuciones interesantes. Bienvenido y enhorabuena por esas contribuciones. Échale un vistazo al formato de otras respuestas. Esta en especial es para mí un poco difícil de seguir. En lugar de poner varias traducciones (y traducción ve vuelta al inglés de una de ellas) y luego las explicaciones como "notas" o "P.S.", creo que sería mejor intercalarlas y **explicar** "en esta traducción he puesto esto o lo otro por esta razón. También podrías ponerlo así o asá por esta otra". Así es más fácil seguir el razonamiento.