# Why do we use imperfect when describing emotions in the past tense?

Tags: gramática, pretérito-imperfecto

I was wondering why we describe emotions in the past tense using the imperfect tense, because if you were saying "I was sad", I would think to translate it to "Yo fui triste", but it would actually be "Yo estaba triste", I was being sad.  Why is this?

---

Me preguntaba por qué describimos las emociones en tiempo pasado usando el tiempo imperfecto, porque si dices "I was sad", pensarías traducirlo a "Yo fui triste", pero en realidad debería ser "Yo estaba triste". ¿Por qué es esto?

Comment: This is actually a question about [the difference between the imperfect and the preterit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/417/when-should-you-use-the-preterite-or-the-imperfect-to-express-past-time?rq=1). If the answers to that question are enough to solve your doubts, just say so.

Comment: Follow Pablos's suggestion and think that it also depends on what you mean. i.e if you want to say "I was a sad person" you use "yo **fui** una persona triste" and it depends if you are using **ser** or **estar** for a permanent or temporary state also.

Comment: I think this is mostly a question regarding the differences between **ser** or **estar**. **"Yo estaba triste" (imperfecto)** is equally valid as  **"Yo estuve triste" (indefinido)**. **Yo fui triste** is wrong only because it is using the wrong verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está en el artículo abajo pero no puedo copiarlo por completo. Pero se puede leer al abrir el PDF y es muy interesante:

**EL VALOR DEL IMPERFECTO DEL INDICATIVO EN ESPAÑOL**

Mira el primero punto bajo:

Los valores del imperfecto:

**Aspecto imperfectivo: "expresa acciones, procesos o estados del pasado en una visión inacabada: Al mediodía, llovía".**

- *Yo estaba triste.* Es un estado de ánimo en el pasado,  y por lo tanto inacabado.

[artículo citado arriba](http://filcat.uab.cat/clt/publicacions/reports/pdf/GGT-03-1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Because generally speaking, the feeling lasted for some time.

In contrast, "Sentí rabia" -- loosely, "I felt a flash of anger" -- shows the rarer example where the feeling was experienced in a flash, and so we use the other past tense ("Sentí rabia").

But if you felt sad yesterday, that covers a fuzzy period.  It might be for several hours or it could be the whole day.  Either way, you need the tense I personally call the *descriptive past*.

Note that if you wanted to put "I felt sad" in the simple past (*pretérite*), then you'd want either "Me sentí triste," or "Estuve triste."  One doesn't combine a form of the verb *ser* with "triste."  (I'm not sure there's a reason for this other than what's customary.)

However, the natural way to say this is "Estaba triste" or "Me sentía triste."