# How would you express giving a command to yourself in Spanish?

Tags: verbos, imperativo

As there is no singular first person imperative form for Spanish verbs (as far as I know), I was wondering whether there is an equivalent to the, possibly idiomatic, English expression of a person giving themselves a command.

E.g. Someone trying to answer a question and saying to themselves 'Think!'

Comment: This is nothing about "tenses", a term which means "time" such as past / present / future. Retagging.

Comment: @hippietrail: Imperative is usually considered a verb tense, even if it doesn't relate (directly) to "time."

Comment: @Flimzy: No, *[imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood)* is considered a verb ***[mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood)***. I know in English many people mix them up these days, they didn't always do so and I don't know if Spanish speakers do. A site at the expert level on language / linguistic themes, which will receive many questions about correctness should endeavour to be as clear and accurate as possible. Sorry if it sounds like nagging or nitpicking, hopefully it's constructive and educational advice toward a better site where we can nip things in the bud.

Comment: Notice I didn't say it was correct to consider it a verb tense; only that it usually is. :)  Your point is well taken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Spanish you use the second person singular to refer to yourself in the imperative way.
For `Think!` you will say `¡Piensa!` (or `¡Pensá!` in *voseo* regions of South America).

You cannot say that for the first person, so you always refer to yourself in the second person for the imperative (as in English).

Answer (score 3):

All Spanish imperatives follow the subjunctive, with the sole exception of the present tense second person singular familiar (tú) positive form (and the vosotros form, in places that use it).

The first person singular form is usually considered absent for imperatives, but you can use the second person familiar or the third person subjunctive which is conveniently the same as the first person subjunctive. The first person plural imperative follows the subjunctive rule regularly (it's the form that uses the "let" form in English).

If you're really giving yourself a command or suggestion, you might also consider using the first person plural. Sometimes it sounds less crazy.

So for pensar (think):

- Self, think. --> *piense* or *piensa*
- You, think. --> *piensa*
- You (formal), think. --> *piense*
- Let us think. (or: Let's think.) --> *pensemos*
- You (plural), think. --> *piensen*

[Indirect speech](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/369/does-indirect-speech-in-spanish-require-changes-in-tense-mood-etc) imperatives follow the subjunctive sequence of tenses.